# The given key was not present in the dictionary

Tags: solr

I am trying to migrate a Sitecore application from 8.x to 9.2. This instance uses SolrNet. We are getting the below error when trying to access the CM node.

```
The given key was not present in the dictionary.
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: System.Collections.Generic.KeyNotFoundException: The given key was not present in the dictionary.

Source Error:

An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.

Stack Trace:


[KeyNotFoundException: The given key was not present in the dictionary.]
   System.ThrowHelper.ThrowKeyNotFoundException() +36
   System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2.get_Item(TKey key) +52
   SolrNet.Utils.Container.DoGetInstance(Type serviceType, String key) +25
   CommonServiceLocator.ServiceLocatorImplBase.GetInstance(Type serviceType, String key) +54

[ActivationException: Activation error occurred while trying to get instance of type ISolrMoreLikeThisHandlerQueryResultsParser`1, key ""]
   CommonServiceLocator.ServiceLocatorImplBase.GetInstance(Type serviceType, String key) +155
   CommonServiceLocator.ServiceLocatorImplBase.GetInstance() +54
   Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider.Logging.SolrLoggingSerializer..ctor() +155
   Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider.LinqToSolrIndex`1..ctor(SolrSearchContext context, IExecutionContext[] executionContexts, IQueryOptimizer queryOptimizer, QueryMapper`1 queryMapper, IIndexValueFormatter indexFieldFormatter, IQueryableFactory queryableFactory, IExpressionParser parser) +430
   Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider.Factories.SolrLinqToIndexFactory.Create(IProviderSearchContext context, IExecutionContext[] executionContexts) +658
   Sitecore.ContentSearch.Abstractions.AbstractSearchContext.GetQueryable(IExecutionContext[] executionContexts) +91
   Sitecore.ContentTesting.ContentSearch.TestingSearch.GetAllTests() +194
   Sitecore.ContentTesting.Pipelines.GetContentEditorWarnings.GetContentTestingWarnings.AddSuspendedTestWarning(GetContentEditorWarningsArgs args) +69
   Sitecore.ContentTesting.Pipelines.GetContentEditorWarnings.GetContentTestingWarnings.Process(GetContentEditorWarningsArgs args) +41
   (Object , Object ) +9
   Sitecore.Pipelines.CorePipeline.Run(PipelineArgs args) +484
   Sitecore.Pipelines.DefaultCorePipelineManager.Run(String pipelineName, PipelineArgs args, String pipelineDomain, Boolean failIfNotExists) +236
   Sitecore.Pipelines.DefaultCorePipelineManager.Run(String pipelineName, PipelineArgs args, String pipelineDomain) +22
```

Not sure how these are linked but if we remove the below pipelines , then CM is coming up correctly

```
<processor ref="CompanyName.Pipelines.Initialize.SolrNetSiteCoreInitialization, CompanyName" reusable="false" factory="NinjectSitecoreFactory" type="1">
          <enableRequestLogging>true</enableRequestLogging>
          <enableResponseLogging>false</enableResponseLogging>
        </processor>
```

The SolrNetSiteCoreInitialization class inherits from a BaseClass , which takes in Indexname as input and initializes connection to SOLR

**EDIT** - Adding Pipeline codes

```
public class SolrNetSiteCoreInitialization : BaseSolrNetCoreInitialization
    {
        public SolrNetScanSiteCoreInitialization([Named("ContentWebRequestFactory")] IHttpWebRequestFactory httpWebRequestFactory) : base(httpWebRequestFactory)
        {

        }

        public override void Process(PipelineArgs args)
        {
            InitializeCore<CalendarEventsSearchResultSolrNet>(Constants.SITE_INDEX_NAME);
        }
    }

public abstract class BaseSolrNetCoreInitialization
    {
        public bool EnableRequestLogging { get; set; }
        public bool EnableResponseLogging { get; set; }

        private readonly IHttpWebRequestFactory _httpWebRequestFactory;

        protected BaseSolrNetCoreInitialization(IHttpWebRequestFactory httpWebRequestFactory)
        {
            _httpWebRequestFactory = httpWebRequestFactory;
        }

        public abstract void Process(Sitecore.Pipelines.PipelineArgs args);

        protected void InitializeCore<T>(string core)
        {
            var solrUrl = Settings.GetSetting("ContentSearch.Solr.ServiceBaseAddress") + "/" + core;            

            var baseSolrConnection = new FactoryEnabledPostSolrConnection(new SolrConnection(solrUrl) 
            {
                HttpWebRequestFactory = _httpWebRequestFactory
            }, solrUrl);

            var loggingSolrConnection = new SolrLoggingConnection(baseSolrConnection, EnableRequestLogging, EnableResponseLogging);

            Startup.Init<T>(loggingSolrConnection); //Initialize SolrNet
        }
    }
```

---

Comment: My guess is this has something to do with your custom code. You may need to share that so that folks can help see which dictionary key it is trying to load that does not exist.

Comment: ok, added the same.

Comment: This issue is related to initialization of Servicelocator . The issue and its resolution is described in this blog - https://xcentium.com/blog/2018/05/11/how-to-use-custom-solrnet-calls-with-sitecore